The number of $1$-s in the binary form of $10^k$ is always more than $k$ when $k>87$?
I originally guessed that it's correct for all natural number $k$ - I verified the case when $k\le 11$ by myself.
Then I asked for a proof in another website. Some users there found $4$ counter-examples: $k=19,25,38,87$. Take $k=19$ for example, $10^{19}=1000101011000111001000110000010010001001111010000000000000000000_2$, there are only $19$ digit $1$-s, not more than $k=19$.
One user checked that there are no more counter-example when $1\le k\le 10^7$. I want to know if these four are the only counter-examples.

tricky. Legendre's formula for the factorial https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula#Alternate_form  just says that $s_2(10^k) < \frac{\log 5}{\log 2} ; k ;; $  That is, the multiplier of $k$ does not grow without bound, but oscillates between $0$  and about $2.3219 ;.  ;$   Considerably more work is required

Multiplying by $2$ does not change number of $1$s in binary, so it suffices to look at $5^k$. Also A118738 gives number of $1$s. It's conjectured there that $\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{a_k}{k}=\log_4 5 \approx 1.160964$, this would give positive answer for sufficiently large $k$.
